# How to create public policies for specific nested folders in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and inside it I have some folders but the objects inside folders are going to be created dynamically so in simple terms I can say it like this:

```
main_users/someIDNumber/uploaded
```

`someIDNumber` is dynamic and it is different every time a user is created.
Now I want to give `GetObject` permission to all objects inside "uploaded" folder just for all users to a specific refer which is my website.

I have tried this in my bucket policies but it doesn't work:

```
arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/main_users/*/uploaded/*
```

also this:

```
arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/main_users/*/uploaded
```

But I get access denied on my website side.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me. I did the following:

- Uploaded a file to: `s3://my-bucket/main_users/42/uploaded/foo.txt`
- Created a `stack` IAM user with the policy shown below
- Ran `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/main_users/42/uploaded/foo.txt . --profile stack`
- The file copied successfully

The policy was:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/main_users/*/uploaded/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It failed when I tried to copy a file with:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/main_users/24/something/foo.txt . --profile stack
```

Please note that if you are trying to list (`ls`) a folder, you will need a different policy. The above was a test of `GetObject`, not of listing a bucket.

While I put these policies on a specific IAM user, it should work the same in a Bucket Policy. Just make sure that you have edited **S3 Block Public Access** to enable the content of the bucket to be publicly accessible.